# Unidentified Network - Local Area Connection cannot be renewed - timed out while contacting DHCP server

Tags: networking, internet, dhcp

For over a day now, I have been confronted by an `Unidentified Network` and that dastardly yellow triangle about the connection icon! Below, as you can see, I have attempted various solutions to this issue, to no avail. Running the Windows Network Diagnostics troubleshooting program, I can see that apparently, my connection does not have a valid IP configuration, from which I can only surmise that my PC is somehow not receiving a valid config... Has anyone else had this insufferable issue? To clarify, every other device connected to this network is in fully working order, so the issue assuredly lies with this device!

**Note- it seems that I cannot ping 127.0.0.1**

Results of executing `ipconfig /all` - [info](https://pastebin.com/5tnzCgmA)

**What I have tried:**

1. Used software to identify missing/broken drivers, found the drivers pertaining directly to my PC's specifications, uninstalled those old drivers and then installed their up-to-date versions. This had no effect.
2. Navigated to the sub-menu `Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Network Connections -> Local Area Connection (Properties) -> Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) -> Properties`. then set the IP address options to "Obtain an IP address automatically". This had no effect, as I had already been receiving IP configurations from the DHCP server...
3. Attempted to reset my network via a number of `netsh` commands: `netsh winsock reset`, `netsh int ip reset`,`ipconfig /flushdns`. These had no effect.
4. Attempted to use `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` in order to receive a new IP configuration. When using `/release`, my Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection has no Connection-specific DNS suffix, and no Default Gateway. When subsequently using `/renew`, I am presented with an **interesting** error: `An error occurred while renewing Local Area Connection Adapter : unable to contact your DHCP server. Request has timed out.` I am not sure what I could have done to cause this.
5. Powered off my device, modem, and router, for 5 minutes. Then, I enabled both the router and modem, and after two minutes, powered on my PC. This had no effect on the issue.
6. Used System Restore points to attempt repair of any sort of corrupted driver or file of sorts. This had no effect.

Comment: I would definitely at this point try a USB LAN card to see if you might have a defective LAN card

Comment: Hey, John, I just did an additional test! It seems that I cannot ping `127.0.0.1` at all, all my requests get timed out. Some have said this may be a driver issue, but I am not sure what additional drivers I might need to install... How can I learn what I must install yet?

Comment: You said above you reinstalled the drivers.  Check the card manufacturer's support site to see if there is a newer driver. I assume this is Windows 10.

Comment: John, when looking for drivers, is there anything besides just the Network Adapter driver I should be looking for?

Comment: You might try updating BIOS. Otherwise, the NIC driver stands on its own. Even BIOS does not usually impact NIC drivers.

Comment: Just updated my NIC driver a bit ago, but it doesn't seem to have had any effect at all... I just tested ipconfig /renew again. It still times me out when contacting the DHCP server or pinging 127.0.0.1

Comment: I would try an external NIC and see if that works.

Comment: Is there any way I can just completely reset all of these network settings to their defaults? Perhaps something such as that would rid me of this issue, because I can't even fathom what is happening..

Comment: You did all this above. I read through your post. Try an external card. If that works, it is the internal NIC. If it does not work, you probably need to back up Windows and install Windows fresh.

Comment: Is there perhaps additional information which I can give that would give more clarity? Here is the information I get from using ipconfig /all: https://pastebin.com/5tnzCgmA

Comment: The IP config is generally OK but you are getting the Auto Answer NO IP. I actually think you network card is working, but something is so seriously bashed and broken (given all of your tests in the first post) that starting again with Windows is very likely the best response here.

Comment: Do you think, then, that these things would likely be resolved with a fresh installation of windows? If so, then thank you for the help :)

Comment: That depends. The NIC "appears" to be working, but by all means try an external NIC. If not an internal NIC hardware issue, then a fresh Windows install should work.

Comment: Have you tried hard-coding an IP address instead of relying on DHCP and/or this particular NIC's ability to use DHCP on your LAN? I've occasionally had issues with DHCP that I was able to get around by reserving and assigning a specific IP address to the card. If you do this you should configure your modem/router so the IP you pick for the card isn't included in the pool of addresses it rents out via DHCP.

Comment: Darth Continent what IP would I use to do this?

Comment: An IP just outside the DHCP range of your router. Log into the router, determine the IP range and give the machine an IP outside of the DHCP range

Comment: I am a bit confused with this. If I cannot even ping 127.0.0.1 or use ipconfig /renew, how can I possibly detect the machine and assign it an accepted IP via the router?

Comment: I do not think static IP will solve your issue. It was a decent suggestion but the issues you have with your network connection have not been resolved with any of the numerous suggestions